# javascript parser for a string which contains .ini data

Tags: javascript, parsing

If a string contains a .ini file data  , How can I parse it in JavaScript ?
Is there any JavaScript parser which will help in this regard?

here , typically string contains the content after reading a configuration file. (reading cannot be done through javascript , but somehow I gather .ini info in a string.)

Comment: Ini files may vary in format, are you just talking about a string of newline-seperated key-value pairs, or is there also sections, comments and so forth... desired input and output would do good

Comment: yeah , it contains sections , key value pair , comments.

Comment: I suggest now its time to move from ini to other formals like Json to Yaml. Better and easier to parse with readily available options.

Answer (score 26):

I wrote a javascript function inspirated by [node-iniparser.js](https://github.com/shockie/node-iniparser/blob/master/lib/node-iniparser.js)

```
function parseINIString(data){
    var regex = {
        section: /^\s*\[\s*([^\]]*)\s*\]\s*$/,
        param: /^\s*([^=]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/,
        comment: /^\s*;.*$/
    };
    var value = {};
    var lines = data.split(/[\r\n]+/);
    var section = null;
    lines.forEach(function(line){
        if(regex.comment.test(line)){
            return;
        }else if(regex.param.test(line)){
            var match = line.match(regex.param);
            if(section){
                value[section][match[1]] = match[2];
            }else{
                value[match[1]] = match[2];
            }
        }else if(regex.section.test(line)){
            var match = line.match(regex.section);
            value[match[1]] = {};
            section = match[1];
        }else if(line.length == 0 && section){
            section = null;
        };
    });
    return value;
}
```

2017-05-10 updated: fix bug of keys contains spaces.

**EDIT:**

[Sample of ini file read and parse](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dad852cde5df545ed81f1bc334ea6f72)

Comment: This works well for me - thanks for posting it. One caveat is that, unlike most INI handling functions, the sections and settings returned by this parser are case sensitive.

Comment: I fixed the case of keys conatins spaces. you can try it again. @m1alesis

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function who's able to parse ini data from a string to an object! (on client side)

```
function parseINIString(data){
var regex = {
    section: /^\s*\[\s*([^\]]*)\s*\]\s*$/,
    param: /^\s*([\w\.\-\_]+)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/,
    comment: /^\s*;.*$/
};
var value = {};
var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
var section = null;

for(x=0;x<lines.length;x++)
{

    if(regex.comment.test(lines[x])){
        return;
    }else if(regex.param.test(lines[x])){
        var match = lines[x].match(regex.param);
        if(section){
            value[section][match[1]] = match[2];
        }else{
            value[match[1]] = match[2];
        }
    }else if(regex.section.test(lines[x])){
        var match = lines[x].match(regex.section);
        value[match[1]] = {};
        section = match[1];
    }else if(lines.length == 0 && section){//changed line to lines to fix bug.
        section = null;
    };

}

return value;
}
```

Comment: This code is really awesome !!! there is a little error in it (reference to line is undefined), I changed it to lines and it worked !!! "}else if(lines.length == 0 && section){"

Answer (score 4):

You could try the [config-ini-parser](https://github.com/shangerxin/config-ini), it's similar to python [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) without I/O operations

It could be installed by npm or bower. Here is an example:

```
var ConfigIniParser = require("config-ini-parser").ConfigIniParser;
var delimiter = "\r\n"; //or "\n" for *nux

parser = new ConfigIniParser(delimiter); //If don't assign the parameter delimiter then the default value \n will be used
parser.parse(iniContent);
var value = parser.get("section", "option");
parser.stringify('\n'); //get all the ini file content as a string
```

For more detail you could check the project main page or from the [npm package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config-ini-parser)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other responses i've modified it so you can have nested sections :)

```
function parseINI(data: string) {
  let rgx = {
    section: /^\s*\[\s*([^\]]*)\s*\]\s*$/,
    param: /^\s*([^=]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/,
    comment: /^\s*;.*$/
  };
  let result = {};
  let lines = data.split(/[\r\n]+/);
  let section = result;
  lines.forEach(function (line) {
    //comments
    if (rgx.comment.test(line)) return;
    //params
    if (rgx.param.test(line)) {
      let match = line.match(rgx.param);
      section[match[1]] = match[2];
      return;
    }
    //sections
    if (rgx.section.test(line)) {
      section = result
      let match = line.match(rgx.section);
      for (let subSection of match[1].split(".")) {
        !section[subSection] && (section[subSection] = {});
        section = section[subSection];
      }
      return;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function similar to `parse_ini_string` in php written for JavaScript:

```js
function nabegheParseIniString(iniString, processSections = true, scannerMode = 'raw', pairSeparator = '=') {
    if (typeof iniString === 'string') {
        iniString = iniString.trim().split(/\r?\n/).filter(line => line.trim());
    }

    const result = {};
    let category = null;

    iniString.forEach(line => {
        line = line.trim();

        // Skip empty line and comment
        if (!line || line[0] === ';') {
            return;
        }

        // Category
        if (processSections && line[0] === '[' && line.slice(-1) === ']') {
            category = line.slice(1, -1);
            if (!result[category]) {
                result[category] = {};
            }
            return;
        }

        // Key
        const [key, ...valueParts] = line.split('=');
        const trimmedKey = key.trim();

        // Skip empty key
        if (!trimmedKey) {
            return;
        }

        // Value
        const value = valueParts.join('=').trim();

        if (scannerMode === 'normal' && value.includes(pairSeparator)) {
            throw new Error('Invalid ini syntax');
        }

        if (category !== null) {
            result[category][trimmedKey] = value;
        } else {
            result[trimmedKey] = value;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```