# Parse config string into javascript/JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, json, textarea, config

I have a textarea where the user edits configurations. It is formatted like this:

```
foo = 'value'
bar = 2.1
john = false
```

Values can be false, true, floats or strings (no functions). I need to regexp this string to create something like:

```
{
    foo: 'value',
    bar: 2.1,
    john: false
}
```

Is there a library or something for this?

Comment: Good function posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12452845/949476

Comment: I have googled and looked around for about an hour, but I thought I might get some *useful* tips here...

Answer (score 0):

I took this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870019/javascript-parser-for-a-string-which-contains-ini-data/12452845#12452845) which should be a good beginning for your request, and added some further rules to handle the different data types, maybe this helps:

```
var data ="foo = 'value'";
    data +="\n" + "bar = 2.1";
    data += "\n" + "john = false";


function JSONFY(data){
    var regex = {
        section: /^\s*\[\s*([^\]]*)\s*\]\s*$/,
        param: /^\s*([\w\.\-\_]+)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/,
        comment: /^\s*;.*$/
    };
    var value = {};
    var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
    var section = null;


    function handleSection(sec) {
        var isFloat = /^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$/;
        if(sec.match(isFloat)) {
            return parseFloat(sec);
        } else if(sec=='true') {
            return true;
        } else if(sec=='false') {
            return false;
        }
        return sec.replace(/^['"]/,'').replace(/['"]$/,'');
    }

    lines.forEach(function(line){
        if(regex.comment.test(line)){
            return;
        }else if(regex.param.test(line)){
            var match = line.match(regex.param);
            if(section){
                value[section][match[1]] = match[2];
            }else{
                value[match[1]] = handleSection(match[2]);
            }
        }else if(regex.section.test(line)){
            var match = line.match(regex.section);
            value[match[1]] = {};
            section = match[1];
        }else if(line.length == 0 && section){
            section = null;
        };
    });
    return value;
}

console.log(JSONFY(data));
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/8F5hN/) to test.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much you can trust the input data, you can always write a simple function utilising code like the following (uses jQuery for simplicity's sake):

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
var output = '{';
$(lines).each(function(l){
    output += '\n\t' + lines[l].replace(/(\w+)\s=\s(.*)/, '$1: $2,');
});
output = output.substring(0, output.length - 1);
output += '\n}';
$('textarea').val(output);
```

The main point here is that you will want to tweak the regex depending on how strict you want to be (i.e. allow whitespace to be optional with a `?` after the `\s` or make sure the values are a specific format.