# Reading INI file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Am not much familiar with JavaScript and the goal is to read a INI file and get the values. The sample INI file contains below items.

```
[Tutor]
Name = Ajast
Course = Victor

[Order]
Title = MAX New
Ring = 12990
```

I want to read the above contents and store into a map like key value pair.

For e.g.,

```
Key = Name & value = Ajast
```

Like that.....

So far all i could do is, come up with a HTML/JS that will let user select a INI file and then read and show it's content in page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reading file</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var reader = new FileReader();

    function readText(that){

        if(that.files && that.files[0]){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {  
                var output=e.target.result;

                document.getElementById('main').innerHTML= output;
            };//end onload()
            reader.readAsText(that.files[0]);
        }//end if html5 filelist support
    } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />
    <div id="main"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want the above task to be achieved in JavaScript. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

### According to [cuixiping](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988089/cuixiping) answer - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870019/javascript-parser-for-a-string-which-contains-ini-data)

you can use [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dad852cde5df545ed81f1bc334ea6f72) script to read *.ini datas on client side using javaScript :)

```
/* 

Read a ini file

[Section1]
Param1=value1
[Section2]
Param2=value2

*/
var fs = require("fs");

function parseINIString(data){
    var regex = {
        section: /^\s*\[\s*([^\]]*)\s*\]\s*$/,
        param: /^\s*([^=]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/,
        comment: /^\s*;.*$/
    };
    var value = {};
    var lines = data.split(/[\r\n]+/);
    var section = null;
    lines.forEach(function(line){
        if(regex.comment.test(line)){
            return;
        }else if(regex.param.test(line)){
            var match = line.match(regex.param);
            if(section){
                value[section][match[1]] = match[2];
            }else{
                value[match[1]] = match[2];
            }
        }else if(regex.section.test(line)){
            var match = line.match(regex.section);
            value[match[1]] = {};
            section = match[1];
        }else if(line.length == 0 && section){
            section = null;
        };
    });
    return value;
}

try {
    var data = fs.readFileSync('C:\\data\\data.dat', 'utf8');

    var javascript_ini = parseINIString(data);
    console.log(javascript_ini['Section1']);

} 
catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: FYI, once you earn 15 [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to flag questions as duplicates of other questions, as seems to be the case here.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut thank you but i just have 6 reputation =D

Comment: @missnefrat - Can you provide a working sample with HTML also in it that will let user select a INI file from client side and then parse and display INI file content as key value pair?

Comment: @donguy76 you can do it easily with that code i post before!
what's your problem?

Comment: Worked at first attempt :)