# javascript read .ini file

Tags: javascript, html

I tried searching . How do i do it? I'm create html  and i want to read  .ini file by javascript on the client Not in the  server.

I copy code from [javascript parser for a string which contains .ini data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870019/javascript-parser-for-a-string-which-contains-ini-data)

error  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined var fs = require('fs')

```
function parseINIString() {
          var fs = require('fs')
          var data = fs.readFileSync('C:\\test.ini', 'utf8');

            var regex = {
                section: /^\s*\[\s*([^\]]*)\s*\]\s*$/,
                param: /^\s*([\w\.\-\_]+)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/,
                comment: /^\s*;.*$/
            };

            var value = {};
            var lines = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
            var section = null;
            alert(lines);
            for (x = 0; x < lines.length; x++) {

                if (regex.comment.test(lines[x])) {
                    return;
                } else if (regex.param.test(lines[x])) {
                    var match = lines[x].match(regex.param);
                    if (section) {
                        value[section][match[1]] = match[2];
                    } else {
                        value[match[1]] = match[2];
                    }
                } else if (regex.section.test(lines[x])) {
                    var match = lines[x].match(regex.section);
                    value[match[1]] = {};
                    section = match[1];
                } else if (lines.length == 0 && section) {//changed line to lines to fix bug.
                    section = null;
                };  
            }

            return value;
        }
```

Comment: You can't load a file in that way in the browser.

Comment: You can't require node modules in the browser. Instead, pass the string in as an argument. You can use the FileReader api to read in text from input files.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Did you install iniparser?

Comment: If I put the file html on the user's screen for get data in ini file and  input <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=xxx">  with sending values

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the javascript running in a browser is so called 'client script'. There are lots of limitation while writing client script, one of them is that it's not allowed to visit the user file on disk. This is to prevent any injected hacker script from reading private data. And the explicit error you see is about the new key word 'require' which is well known as 'commonjs' module which is introduced by Nodejs usually. The 'fs' is one of the internal module of Nodejs as well.

So if you still consist using client script to get the job done, you have to rewrite the script, not 'require' the 'fs' module. And use the [file reader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to get the content of a file object, which is generated by a [file input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) usually.

[A detailed introduction about how to read local files](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).